# Recognition of images with additional data

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

Good morning everyone, first I would like to make it clear that I began to take my first steps in machine learning yesterday.
I've read most basic items and attended some presentations.
I will participate in a project here a few months that this technology will be applied.
As a beginner I would like to ask a question that I think is silly, but I could not find answers for her.

In presentations and articles, I have seen the creation of a classifier that can classify images or data sets, but never both at the same time.
For example, Iris flower data set, which is used as an example. In this data set we have the characteristics of flowers, such as petal width, but we do not have a visual representation of it. It is possible to fit both and for example, to estimate the width of the petal of a certain image?

I imagine this is a very basic question, but I could not find something suitable for a beginner.

I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning models always work on some abstract data items like vectors, points in multidimensional spaces etc. For the simplicity, let us assume for a moment that ML algorithms work on vectors. Classification therefore would be a task of assigning a label Y to a vector **X**(n).

Now with a data set conversion of values in a row into a vector is relatively easy - well, you have to somehow convert texts onto numbers or vice versa, but it is a standard procedure.

With images it is different. You have to now build a ML-suitable representation of an image. In other words you need to create features (e.g. numerical) describing the image, that you can later use as inputs to your ML.

Examples of such features are: colour histograms, average brightness, number of edges, various convolutions etc. There can be more complicated, semantic features like the presence of a human on the picture. Calculating these however is much more difficult.

So summing up - you can build a classifier on both the image and dataset, but it basically means transforming both into a set of features.